# An easy way to remember PEMDAS

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I'm having trouble remembering PEMDAS (in regards to precedence in mathematical equations), ie:

- Parentheses
- Exponentiation
- Multiplication & Division
- Addition & Subtraction

I understand what all of the above mean, but I am having trouble keeping this in my head. Can you recommend any tricks or tips you use to remember this.

Thanks

Comment: This was incorrectly tagged as being related to functional equations.

Comment: you may want to try: http://xkcd.com/992/

Comment: Don't remember PEMDAS.

Comment: Maybe you find BEDMAS easier to remember? Brackets, Exponentiation, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction. (I changed that from BODMAS [Brackets Off ...] to contain your inclusion of Exponentiation)

Comment: Don't remember it.  Tell your teachers and those who use infix notation to either use prefix notation for terms, use postfix notation for terms, or completely parenthesize terms in infix notation.

Comment: I just joined to make this comment: My kid just told me "PEMDAS" means Multiplication has higher precedence then Division, Additional has higher precedence over Subtraction. For pete's sake, forget about PEMDAS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PEMDAS is an acronym to help you remember. try different forms of mnemonic devices, like acrostics:
Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally; 
Pancake Explosion Many Deaths Are Suspected; 
Purple Egglants Make Dinner Alot Sickening; 
Pink Elephants March, Dance, And Sing;
Pizza ended my donuts addiction Saturday

Comment: +1: Did you make up these hilarious mnemonics yourself or did you find them in a book?

Comment: lol, i heard them over time from teachers and classmates

Answer (score 8):

I think it makes most sense to remember it in four steps:

1. Parentheses trump everything else -- because that's what they are *for*.
2. Addition and subtraction have the same priority, because they are each other's inverse.
3. Similarly, multiplication and division have the same priority. But that's rarely relevant, because proper mathematics prefers writing division with a faction bar, which delimits its arguments unambiguously without referring to rules.
4. The ordering *between* the various groups of operation is chosen such that polynomials work. What "polynomials work" means is that we can use the laws of arithmetic to rewrite everything into something that doesn't need parentheses:

   - Exponentiation must come before multiplication, because then we can rewrite $(2x)(3x)$ into $6x^2$. If multiplication had higher priority than exponentiation we'd need either parentheses as $6(x\text{ to the power of }2)$, or introducing square roots to make $\sqrt 6 \cdot x\text{ to the power of }2$, both of which are inconvenient.
   - Multiplication must come before addition and subtraction, because the distributive law allows us to rewrite an arbitrary product of sums into a sum of products, but not the other way around:
     $$ (5+x)\cdot y = 5y+xy $$
     but there's no product of sums that correspond to $3x+5y$, so it would be inconvenient if we couldn't write that without parentheses but had to write it as $(3\text{ times }x)+(5\text{ times }y)$.

Comment: Writing division with a fraction bar is a way of hiding brackets:
$$\frac{\color{red}{a}}{\color{blue}{b}} \space\equiv\space \left(\color{red}{a} \div \color{blue}{b}\right)$$

Answer (score 7):

Well, I suggest you remember the word 'pemdas'.
Another way:

- brackets were designed to be evaluated first, so they go first
- the other operations go from advanced to simple

Comment: Yup, not sure you can get much simpler than a one word acronym. Otherwise there's nothing so good as practice!

Answer (score 5):

please eat mom's delicious apple strudel

Comment: Why it is downvoted? It is a proper answer for a question about memorization.

Comment: Not the downvoter (to be exact, can't). While it's a proper answer, a short explanation might help, like *"Here is how I memorize it"*. Also, using correct formatting might give a hint to each letter. Else, it looks like a (somewhat) nonsense answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend thinking about precedence a different way.

- What did you learn first?  Addition and subtraction.
- What did you learn after that?  Multiplication and Division.
- What after that?  Exponentiation.

If you perform these operations in the opposite order that you learned them, you don't have to remember about anyone's Dear Aunt Sally.  When these rules are not enough to avoid ambiguity, use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better acronym would be

$P$arenthesis $E$xponents $F$actors $T$erms.

Students often think that multiplication has higher priority than division because $M$ is before $D$ in $PEMDAS$.

However, if you want a funny way to remember $PEMDAS$, then

$P$lease $E$xcuse $M$y $D$ope $A$ss $S$wag.

Answer (score 1):

- Please Excuse My Dreadful Art Skills
- Please Eat My Delicious Anaconda Snakes
- Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally

The first $2$ I came up with. The last is a commonly used phrase to remember PEMDAS.

Answer (score 0):

Daan's suggestion of remembering that parenthesis go first, then advanced to simple is good because there is some meaning in it instead of just having a random word. But if you want to remember a word, and you remember that multiplication and division go together (they're inverses of each other), and addition and subtraction go to gether (again, they're inverses), you just have to remember PEMA or PEDS or whatever, and then fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I always taught students to remember this mnemonic as **PE(MD)(AS)** since multiplication and division are performed left-to-right in the order they appear, just like addition and subtraction.

I'm sure many have seen this viral Facebook question:
$$6 \div 2 \ ( 1 + 2 ) = \ ?$$

Is is 9 or 1? [Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPe1aBW_YCg) that shows you how it's done.

Comment: division and subtraction aren't commutative operations, when using them you should always employ parentheses.

Comment: I think that we should get rid of the dreadful $\div$. The only time I have used it is when I teach it.

Answer (score 0):

**Aunt Sally (PEMDAS) has been banished from mathematics.**

Read this *very short* article to understand why:
https://blogs.edweek.org/teachers/coach_gs_teaching_tips/2011/01/math_teachers_please_excuse_dear_aunt_sally--forever.html

**PEMA** is the new mnemonic: **Purple Elephants Munching Apples** ???

1. Parentheses (and other grouping symbols).
2. Exponents.
3. Multiplication and Division ***from left to right.***
4. Addition and Subtraction ***from left to right.***

The importance of ***from left to right*** is absent in PEMDAS.

Answer (score 0):

I am a step by step person. 
(remembering always left to right)
1. Parenthesis 
2. exponents
3. multiply/divide
4. add/subtract

Answer (score -1):

I Think a good P.E.M.D.A.S Is

Parrots
eat up
magic
dassies
and
snoozed off

Answer (score -1):

**P**lease **E**xcuse **M**y **D**ear **A**unt **S**ally.

Comment: This is mentioned in the upvoted and accepted answer.